# Pull an object from a hashtable and cast it to another object

Tags: c#

I have a `Hashtable` called `hash` whose first value is a GUID and the second one is an object of type `InstallationFiles`. I want to be able to do the following:

```
    InstallationFiles ifiles = (InstallationFiles)hash[objectGuid];
```

Even though this one returns the right value `hash[objectGuid]`, I also find the entry with `hash[objectGuid]` as key in the Hashtable, however this one `(InstallationFiles)hash[objectGuid]` always returns null. Why could that be?

UPDATE.

Ok, I'll show more code.
The user is in this window. He/She clicks on an add file button to add a file to the list.  [image]

Another window pops up: [image]

When a user clicks on the add file button in the first form (first picture), the following method is triggered:

Setup_Generator.cs (My main form object, first picture):

```
    private void addFileOrDirectory(string ifFileOrDirectory)
    {            
           if (ifFileOrDirectory == "File")
           {
             //here I initialize the object of the second form (second picture)
              efef = new editFileEntryForm(info.TheRightProgramFilesDirectoryUserView, info.ApplicationName, "File", null);
            if (efef.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
               //every file entry has a unique guid
                Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
                //efef.InstFiles is an object of type InstallationFiles (code in the next block)
                hash.Add(g, efef.InstFiles);
                item1 = new ListViewItem(efef.InstFiles.File);
                item1.SubItems.Add(efef.InstFiles.DestDir);
                listViewDerivative1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { item1 });
                item1.Tag = g;
            }
        }
```

editFileEntryForm.cs, or second form shown in the second picture:

```
    class editFileEntryForm 
    {
    public Classes.InstallationFiles InstFiles = null;
    //...
    public editFileEntryForm(string instDir, string appName, string fileOrDir, Classes.InstallationFiles instFiles) 
    {
     //...
        if (instFiles != null)
        {
          InstFiles = instFiles;
          sourceFileTextBox.Text = instFiles.File;
          this.destinationDirComboBox.SelectedIndex = instFiles.DestinationDirSelectedIndx;
          this.ifFileExistsComboBox.SelectedIndex = instFiles.FileExistsSelectedIndex;
        }
    }
    private void okButtonClick() 
    {
      if (FileOrDir == "File") 
        {
            //here I initialize an object which I add to a hashtable in Setup_generator.cs
            InstFiles = new Classes.InstallationFiles(this.sourceFileTextBox.Text, 
                                                      destinationDirComboBox.Text,
                                                      NSISvariables[destinationDirComboBox.Text],
                                                      NSISvariables[ifFileExistsComboBox.Text],
                                                      ifFileExistsComboBox.SelectedIndex,
                                                      destinationDirComboBox.SelectedIndex
                                                      );
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
    }
```

Up to this point everything goes to the plan - the values are saved in a Hashtable hash, the key being a GUID and the value an InstallationFiles object. When a user selects an entry an clicks on edit in the main form (Setup_Generator.cs or first picture), I do the following:

```
    private void edit()
    {
        //retrieve the selected item and its GUID
        ListViewItem lvi = listViewDerivative1.SelectedItems[0];
        string objectGuid = lvi.Tag.ToString();
        //(Classes.InstallationFiles)hash[objectGuid] returns null, even though an object with the given GUID exists in the hashtable!
        Classes.InstallationFiles ifiles = (Classes.InstallationFiles)hash[objectGuid];
        //initializing a new form to edit a selected entry
        efef = new    editFileEntryForm(this.info.TheRightProgramFilesDirectoryUserView, this.info.ApplicationName, "File", ifiles);
        if (efef.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
           //This is my ultimate goal: replace old values with new ones in the HASHTABLE hash!
           //not working, because hash[objectGuid] as Classes.InstallationFiles) returns as null
           (hash[objectGuid] as Classes.InstallationFiles).File = efef.InstFiles.File;
           (hash[objectGuid] as Classes.InstallationFiles).DestDir = efef.InstFiles.DestDir;     
           (hash[objectGuid] as Classes.InstallationFiles).DestDirNSISVariable = efef.InstFiles.DestDirNSISVariable;
           (hash[objectGuid] as Classes.InstallationFiles).IfFileExistsNSISVariable = efef.InstFiles.IfFileExistsNSISVariable;
        {    
        }
        }
```

Comment: Showing the code instead of describing it might help us spot the error.

Comment: The problem lies somewhere else than you think. Please provide an [mcve].

Comment: `var obj = hash[objectGuid]; InstallationFiles ifiles = (InstallationFiles)obj;` ifiles could be null only if obj is null (otherwise it would throw `InvalidCastException`)

Comment: Why aren't you using a dictionary? `Dictionary<Guid, InstallationFiles>` seems to be exactly what you wish you had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling

```
efef = new editFileEntryForm(info.TheRightProgramFilesDirectoryUserView,
       info.ApplicationName, "File", null);
```

but you pass `instFiles` as null

```
public editFileEntryForm(string instDir, string appName, string fileOrDir, Classes.InstallationFiles instFiles) 
{
 //... instFiles - null here
    if (instFiles != null)
    {
      InstFiles = instFiles;
      sourceFileTextBox.Text = instFiles.File;
      this.destinationDirComboBox.SelectedIndex = instFiles.DestinationDirSelectedIndx;
      this.ifFileExistsComboBox.SelectedIndex = instFiles.FileExistsSelectedIndex;
    }
}
```

so, when you call `hash.Add(g, efef.InstFiles);` you are passing `null` value as `efef.InstFiles`

Thats why you hashtable contains null-values.